# Copying and Pasting between Workbooks VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Please bear with me I am still learning VBA and could do with a little help.

I am trying to copy data from one workbook to another even though there I have found many answers on this I am unable to
Understand the code as its quite complicated. I was hoping if someone could help me with a basic code which is pretty easy to read and understand.

I am currently looking to copy all data off 3 different workbooks  and paste it into 1 workbook across 3 worksheets.

For example I have 3 workbooks called

AA
BB
CC

I want to copy all the data (value only) from these workbooks and paste then into workbook called

Main

But I want that data from AA.to go into Main Worksheet1 and
But I want that data from BB to go into Main Worksheet2 and
But I want that data from CC to go into Main Worksheet3

I hope I have explained this question properly and I appreciate any help.

Comment: This isn't a free coding site; what do you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have supplied no code, this should be sufficient enough to get you started. You'll need to edit this and fix this to suite your needs.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As WorkBook, Wb3 As Workbook
    Dim MainBook As Workbook

    'Open All workbooks first:
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
    Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
    Set Wb3 = Workbooks.Open(" path to copying book ")
    Set MainBook = Workbooks.Open(" path to destination book ")

    'Now, copy what you want from wb1:
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
    'Now, paste to Main worksheet:
    MainBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    'Now, copy what you want from wb2:
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
    'Now, paste to Main worksheet:
    MainBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    'Now, copy what you want from wb3:
    wb3.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy
    'Now, paste to Main worksheet:
    MainBook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    'Close Wb's:
    Wb1.Close
    Wb2.Close
    Wb3.Close
    MainBook.Save
    MainBook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, Many Thanks for your quick reply. I just have 2 questions. When adding this code do I just add it to the main workbook or would i have to add it on all 3? 2nd question when I am running this macro each time does all 4 workbooks need to be open?

Comment: @ShahMiah You could have this within a 3rd party non-related workbook, or eliminate the open and close tags for the MainBook and set MainBook as ActiveWorkbook. Then you could place the code within MainBook. As for your second question, the set method will open up those workbooks, so you shouldn't need to do anything besides for execute the code.

Comment: Thanks Brendon

I have tried the code with the following but i am getting an error 400.

Here is what i have added

Comment: @ShahMiah Make sure the MainBook has a sheet 1,2,and 3 or add further code to create sheets like "Sheets.Add.Name = "Test"".  Also, make sure you have extensions on your directory I.E. "C:\Users\Shah\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"

Comment: Thank you Brendon, You have been awesome you new code worked perfectly! Cant thank you enough