# How to copy data between two Excel workbooks?

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I am trying to write an Excel add-in that would copy data between two workbooks.

What I would like to do is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102348/copying-and-pasting-between-workbooks-vba), but I would like to do that using the `office-js`.

Since `office-js`-based add-ins also work in the web browser, I would probably need to create a new Excel workbook from second (non-opened) workbook data and then copy the data over to the first workbook. I found [the API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook) that allows me to open the workbook, but I am at a loss on how to use that workbook (get the data from it).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Office Web Add-ins have no way of working with more than one open document at a time. It's an interesting idea. Please suggest this on Office Developer Suggestion Box. Or vote up one of the existing suggestions. A couple of possibilities:

[Enable Excel to open a workbook in the same doc](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36073420-enable-excel-js-to-open-a-workbook-in-the-same-doc)

[Copy and paste ...](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/35768350-copy-and-paste-the-required-exist-excel-file-into)